# google play Internal track testing

Tags: google-play

I'm new to android development and uploaded my app to google play "internal track" over a week ago and it still says that it's not reviewed and in "draft" mode.

I'm assuming despite the app not being public and only on the internal track i am still at the mercy of google to review the app before my testers can test it ?. Also , my code for google play billing is returning 0 items. Again... i assume that because i need google to "review" it first and take it out of draft mode before i can test google play billing functionality ?